# Creation of Flyway "schema_version" fails for dashDB

Tags: flyway, dashdb

I'm using Flyway to manage db migration on IBM [dashDB](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/dashdb/). This database organizes by default table content 'by column', which in particular makes the creation of the `"schema_version"` table fail.
To get it to work, the table creation SQL statement should only include the `"ORGANIZE BY ROW"` directive:

`CREATE TABLE (...)
  (...)
) ORGANIZE BY ROW`

What would be the best approach to handle this issue ? I'm looking for a solution that does not impact the default table organization.
Thanks for helping,
Cheers.

Comment: What versiom/plan of dashDB are you using? Could you change `dft_table_org` during the migration?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to change a particular table from column organized to row organized then a "ORGANIZE BY ROW" on the table definition would be the recommended way to approach this. (This seems to be what you're doing)

Changing the default table org will change how tables are created when you don't put an "ORGANIZE BY " in your table ddl.

If you have admin privileges on your dashDB instance you can change the default table org via 'Run SQL' in the dashDB console or using a dashDB client. (for exampl: clp/clpplus)

Set default table organization to ROW:

```
call ADMIN_CMD('UPDATE DB CFG USING DFT_TABLE_ORG ROW');
```

Set default table organization to COLUMN:  (default dashDB configuration)

```
call ADMIN_CMD('UPDATE DB CFG USING DFT_TABLE_ORG COLUMN');
```

Analytics will perform much better with Column organized tables so it's recommended to have the majority of your tables as column organized.

Comment: Thanks - it does not really answer as I mentioned that I did not want to change the db's default org. I'm rather looking for a solution at the Flyway level that would allow me to add this "ORGANIZE BY ROW" option. The only solution I found so far was to path the flyway-core and update the SQL that creates the table.

Answer (score 0):

dashDB will perform best when all tables are column-based.  When you start to mix row and column based tables, many operations are then performed in "compensation" which basically means they won't take full advantage of the columnar engine.

There are currently some compatibility reasons why a columnar table cannot be created and thus a row based table must be used, but the original DDL nor error are stated so I can't tell in this case.  If you can provide the full CREATE TABLE statement and the resulting error (if you have it), I can possibly provide an alternative solution that would allow you to still use all column-based tables.